# no content after shortcode

Tags: shortcode, audio

I hope you guys can help me with this little bug I've encountered. I am using a shortcode to display an audio player in the entries.

This is the code i've put in my functions.php:

```
function html5_audio($atts, $content = null) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    "src" => '',
    "preload"=> 'none',
    "loop" => ''
), $atts));
return '<audio src="'.$src.'" preload="'.$preload.'" loop="'.$loop.'" />';
}
add_shortcode('audio', 'html5_audio');
```

And this is the shortcode:

```
[audio src=""]
```

The shortcode itself is working and displaying the audio player. But any other content that is posted after the shortcode within that post won't appear on the blog. I tried embedding the audio file directly with `<audio>` and it worked. So HTML5 is working alright. Only the shortcode seems to be causing trouble.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the closing [`</audio>`](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_audio.asp) tag at the end.

```
function html5_audio($atts, $content = null) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    "src" => '',
    "preload"=> 'none',
    "loop" => ''
), $atts));
return '<audio src="'.$src.'" preload="'.$preload.'" loop="'.$loop.'" /></audio>';
}
add_shortcode('audio', 'html5_audio');
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel like a fool for overlooking that. I was looking for much more complex problems. It's working now.